# How to assign parameterized constructor object to class type property contract in interface

Tags: c#

I am getting an error while assigning parameterized object to Class Type Property Contract. Following is the code.

```
internal interface IDisplayContents : IHttpHandler
{
   MenuRoute propMenuRoute { get; set; }
}


public class MenuRoute
{

    private string _OriginalRoute = string.Empty;
    private string[] _RouteNodes = null;
    private bool _RouteFound;

    public string OriginalRoute
    {
        get { return _OriginalRoute; }
    }
    public string[] RouteNodes
    {
        get { return _RouteNodes; }
    }
    public bool RouteFound
    {
        get { return _RouteFound; }
    }

    public MenuRoute(string route, bool routeFound)
    {
        _RouteFound = routeFound;
        _RouteNodes = GlobalObjects.SplitString(route,"/");
        if (_RouteNodes.Length .Equals(0))
            _RouteNodes = new string[] { "/" };


        for (int nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex <= _RouteNodes.Length - 1; nodeIndex++)
        {

            _RouteNodes[nodeIndex] = GlobalObjects.SplitString(_RouteNodes[nodeIndex].ToString(), ".aspx")[0];

        }
        _OriginalRoute = route;

    }

public class UrlRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{


    private string _virtualPath;
    public UrlRouteHandler(string virtualPath)
    {
        _virtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {



        IDisplayContents displayContent = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(_virtualPath, typeof(Page)) as IDisplayContents;

        if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["notImplementedUrl"] != null)
        {
            displayContent.propMenuRoute = new MenuRoute("", false);

        }
        else
        {
            RouteValueDictionary routes = requestContext.RouteData.Values;
            int intLevels = routes.Count;
            string strRoute = string.Empty;


            for (int intIterate = 1; intIterate <= intLevels; intIterate++)
            {
                strRoute += routes["level" + intIterate.ToString()] as string + "/";

            }

            displayContent.propMenuRoute = new MenuRoute(strRoute, true);
There comes the error
```

An exception of type System.NullReferenceException' occurred in but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
displayContent.MenuRoute = New MenuRoute(strRoute, True)

```
        }

        return displayContent;

    }

}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there is a typo in the error message and the additional information is actually:

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. displayContent.propMenuRoute = New MenuRoute(strRoute, True)

since otherwise your code wouldn't compile, as `IDisplayContents` does not have a property `MenuRoute`.

---

The only place where `displayContent` is set is in

```
IDisplayContents displayContent = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(_virtualPath, typeof(Page)) as IDisplayContents;
```

This means that if `displayContent` is `null`, then either the `CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath` method returns null or it returns an object of a type that does not implement the `IDisplayContents` interface.

Although i cannot be sure without knowing the implementation of your methods, it seems like `CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath` returns a `Page` object and `Page` does not implement `IDisplayContents`.